# Passing JSON as variable to jsTree

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jstree

I have a variable and I want to pass it to `$('#tree').jstree()`.

Tried:

```
$('#tree').jstree({
    plugins: ["checkbox", "types"],
    "types": {
        "file": {
            "icon": "jstree-file"
        }
    },
    'core': {
        'data':  mdata.data

    }
});
//------------------------------
$('#tree').jstree({
    plugins: ["checkbox", "types"],
    "types": {
        "file": {
            "icon": "jstree-file"
        }
    },
    'core': {
        'data':  JSON.stringify(mdata.data)

    }
});
//------------------------------
 $('#tree').jstree(mdata.data)
```

My JSON variable (`mdata.data`) is already parsed by `JSON.parse()`. I've validated it via jsonlint.com and its valid. Here it is:

```
   [{
    "soslist": [{
        "code_intext": "utf-8",
        "count_of_pages": 2,
        "count_of_records": 7,
        "curobj": "1",
        "obj": "1",
        "page": 1
    }, {
        "code_intext": "utf-8",
        "count_of_pages": 2,
        "count_of_records": 7,
        "curobj": "1",
        "obj": "1",
        "page": 1
    }],
    "system": [{
        "count_of_pages": 2,
        "count_of_records": 7,
        "curobj": "1",
        "page": 1
    }]
}]
```

`mdata.data` in console:

[image]

Is it even possible or jsTree need specific JSON structure and stuff like `id` and `parent_id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jsTree needs specific JSON structure. From their [documentation](https://www.jstree.com/docs/json/):

```
// Expected format of the node (there are no required fields)
{
  id          : "string" // will be autogenerated if omitted
  text        : "string" // node text
  icon        : "string" // string for custom
  state       : {
    opened    : boolean  // is the node open
    disabled  : boolean  // is the node disabled
    selected  : boolean  // is the node selected
  },
  children    : []  // array of strings or objects
  li_attr     : {}  // attributes for the generated LI node
  a_attr      : {}  // attributes for the generated A node
}
```

Your object is in a completely different format, so it won't work.